# Are there examples of "Trappist" beers that lost that label (or ceased to exist)?

Tags: history, trappist

For a pubquiz, I am looking for a "Trappist" beer that lost that label (preferably), or ceased to exist. All I can find are the current 12 Trappists, nothing about old ones.

Comment: "*I once was lost but now I'm found
I was blind but now I see*" I see my pint glass is empty, would you be so kind?

Comment: "lost that label" because not trappist anymore or because never was (and was sued)?

Comment: @AltbierisnotOldBeer because it is not anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [list of vanished (presumably) trappist breweries](http://www.trappistbeer.net/trappist_portalEN.htm) (choose English and the click "Others..." on the left pane.

Here is the list

> Among the breweries which used to brew Trappist beer are these :
>
> - The abbey of La Trappe (France)
> - The abbey of Melleray (France)
> - The abbey of Mont des Cats (France, beer rebrewed by Chimay since 2011)
> - The abbey of Sept Fons (France)
> - The abbey of Chambarand (France)
> - The abbey of Oelenberg (France)
> - The abbey of Notre Dame du Gard (France)
> - The abbey of Notre Dame du Port Du Salut (France)
> - The abbey of Notre Dame du Bon repos (Saint Julien de Cassagnas) (France)
> - The abbey of Notre-Dame de Bonne-Espérance (Échourgnac - France)
> - The abbey of Notre Dame de Staoueli (Algeria under French domination)
> - The abbey of Tegelen (Netherlands)
> - The abbey of Engelszell (Austria, brewing restarted in 2012)
> - The abbey of Banja Luka (Bosnia)
> - The abbey of Mariawald (Germany)
> - It seems that a Trappist brewery also existed in Africa, but we do not have any serious information on this subject. It would be the
>   brewery of the abbey Our Lady of Mokoto in Gisenyi, Rwanda.

*Keep in mind though, that this information might be incorrect.*

If you click the picture on the right side, you'll see some labels which are about 100 years old.

Comment: Can you quote a source within your linked article of ** “Trappist” beers that lost that label (or ceased to exist)?** A little more text for clarity on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @KenGraham Oh, I clicked on the link and it opens the start page, not the list. You should choose English and then click on "Others..." on the left pane.

Answer (score 0):

The La Trappe beer lost for a while the Trappist label (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Koningshoeven_Brewery).
It had, then it lost, and now it has.

Comment: A little more text for clarity on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found that yes. The quiz-question is "which one is not a Trappist", and then of course to have one that is not a Trappist *anymore* would probably make it a little harder.